# Renaming files in python after being downloaded

Tags: python

So, I wrote a script in python to download files from an ftp server.
This script downloads file every hour with windows automated task system.
I wanted to know if it was possible to rename those files after being downloaded and if someone could advise me on how I could do it. 
This is my current code:

```
import shutil
import urllib.request as request
from contextlib import closing

def download(filename):
    with closing(request.urlopen("ftp://BUZZ:NotMyPassword@ftp.usaradio.com/"+filename)) as r:
        with open('C:/MyPath/usanews/'+filename,'wb') as f:
            shutil.copyfileobj(r, f)

files = ["newsbreak128.mp3", "toh35.mp3"]
for file in files:
    download(file)
```

Answer (score 0):

The way to do it without altering your function too much is to pass the value of the filename to download and the name you want to rename the file to in a dictionary format or as tuples in a list. I'll give an example of the latter. If you pass each pair of names (the one to download and its new name), and then specify which one you're trying to grab by index, your function should work.

```
def download(filename):
    with closing(request.urlopen("ftp://BUZZ:NotMyPassword@ftp.usaradio.com/"+filename[0])) as r:
        with open('C:/MyPath/usanews/'+filename[1],'wb') as f:
            shutil.copyfileobj(r, f)

files = [("newsbreak128.mp3","new_name_1.mp3"), ("toh35.mp3","new_name_1.mp3")]
for file in files:
    download(file)
```